# Azure VM add 2 static IPs

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-app-service, windows-server-2012

I am very new at Microsoft Azure. I have set up my VM (Server 2012 R2) and wish to add 2 static IPs to it for both my website domains I will be hosting on the VM.

I have looked around for some tutorials and all seem either out dated or very complex and consuming to understand.

I did find [this page](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-azure/set-azure-vm-static-ip-address) and [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/08/06/step-by-step-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-a-vm-in-a-virtual-network.aspx) as the better of all the bunch but it doesn't mention  anything about how to set up a second static IP.

Any Step by step (with screen shots if possible) would be great in how to go about doing this using the Azure command line.

Answer (score 0):

The links which you have provided only show how to make an internal IP static (a "DIP" in Azure terms).
This won't help you to access your websites over the internet but only from instances within your VNet.

1. The best solution would be to provide your instance with 2 different Public IP addresses, i.e., 2 Instance Level Public IPs (ILPIP) in Azure terms (earlier PIP). Unfortunately, as of now, Azure supports only one ILPIP for each instance. You'll find the details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/).
2. If one of your websites is accepting traffic on 80 and the other on 443 then a possible workaround can be that you create 2 different endpoint mappings, lets say, 1111->80 and 2222->443, and access them as follows -

   a. Using Cloud Service VIP. E.g. - one through CloudServiceVIP:1111 and the other through CloudServiceVIP:2222

   b. [Create 2 Reserve IPs for your VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/#how-to-associate-a-reserved-ip-to-a-running-deployment). E.g. - FirstReservedIP:1111 to access one site and other through SecondReservedIP:2222.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that you don't have to have 2 Public IP addresses in order to support two different sites.  IIS should be able to direct traffic to the proper app based on the name used (host header) for access.

Comment: If this is to be an answer, you might take a couple screenshots or something, or at least mention what tools to invoke to accomplish this traffic direction.